# How to convert a DICOM file with no extension to a .png file or a .jpg file?

Tags: c#, jpeg, dicom

I have a simple C# Console Application that places a dicom file into a stream and then Copies that stream to a .jpg file.  My code creates the file but I'm unable to view the image. Below is the code I am using.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using rzdcxLib;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
       public static void CopyStream(Stream input, Stream output) { 
            byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0) { 
                output.Write(buffer, 0, len); 
            } 
        } 
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Stream myStream = 
             new FileStream("F:\\MIS\\JLoren\\Projects\\" + 
                             "814-Convert for Chandra\\DICOM\\Test\\IM1",
                            FileMode.Open, 
                            FileAccess.Read);
            Stream OutPut = 
             new FileStream("F:\\MIS\\JLoren\\Projects\\" +
                            "814-Convert for Chandra\\DICOM\\Test\\IM1.jpg", 
                            FileMode.Create, 
                            FileAccess.Write);
            CopyStream(myStream, OutPut);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as I can find doing a quick web search, DICOM is some kind of container format that contains patient data, information about the device(s) used to capture the image and ultimately some "pixel data" but this pixel data can contain multiple (and multi-dimensional) images. The images are stored [_"using a variety of standards, including JPEG, JPEG Lossless, JPEG 2000, and Run-length encoding (RLE)"_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DICOM#DICOM_data_format), so simply copying the file contents to a file named .jpg won't work. [Search it](https://www.google.nl/search?q=export+dicom+to+jpeg).

Answer (score 4):

Look [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36014/DICOM-Image-Viewer) for information on the DICOM image format and how to read up DICOM images with C#. Note that these images are often 16 bit grayscale, which means a 8bpp (per-channel) monitor format cannot display these images with their full color range. You will have to choose a value of ["window" and "level"](http://www.eyephysics.com/Madena/MadenaDICOM.html) for your particular conversion. Fixing these values might cause you to lose information in the converted image. See: [Hounsfeld units](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hounsfield_scale).

Also - one of the core tenets of DICOM is that the image be lossless. Ensure that this is acceptable for your purpose before proceeding with a JPG conversion. PNG ought to be ok.

Comment: Although common, there is in fact no requirement that the image is lossless. The image data in many DICOM files is actually compressed with lossy jpg. Simple Google searches seem to corroborate this (for example http://www.mccauslandcenter.sc.edu/mricro/dicom/index.html )

Comment: :) While the format DOES support this - I have never met a client or a medical imaging functional expert who would recommend lossy images - except perhaps as a "preview" or a way of transporting images faster for some sort of application.